# Cannot save editText value in Android AlertDialog popup in OptionsMenu

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-optionsmenu

My code works like this: I click the optionsmenu, select "edit tip rate". Then, a popup appears containing a textfield and a cancel button and a save button. I enter a value in the textfield, then click save. At this point I get a nullpointer exception for the textfield ("field", in the code below)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefs";

    // tip and tax rates
    private String tax_rate;
    private String tip_rate;

    // default tip and tax
    private String default_tax_rate = "10.0";
    private String default_tip_rate = "12.0";

    // tip and tax rate keys
    public static final String TaxRate = "tax_rate_key";
    public static final String TipRate = "tip_rate_key";

    // dialog popup
    final Context context = this;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Retrieve preferences
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(TaxRate)) {
            tax_rate = sharedpreferences.getString(TaxRate, "");
        } else {
            tax_rate = default_tax_rate;
        }

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(TipRate)) {
            tip_rate = sharedpreferences.getString(TipRate, "");
        } else {
            tip_rate = default_tip_rate;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    // This method is called once the menu is selected
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        // If edit tip rate is selected
        case R.id.item1:
            View promptView1 = layoutInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.prompt_tip, null);

            editDialog(promptView1, TipRate, R.id.userInput_tip);
            break;

        // If edit tax rate is selected
        case R.id.item2:
            View promptView2 = layoutInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.prompt_tax, null);
            editDialog(promptView2, TaxRate, R.id.userInput_tax);
            break;

        }
        return true;

    }

    private void editDialog(View promptView, final String key, int id) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

        // set prompts.xml to be the layout file of the alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

        // setup a dialog window
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Save",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                final EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(id);
                                if (field.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context,
                                            "enter a valid number",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                else {
                                    // Read the value inside the textfield as a
                                    // string
                                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
                                            .getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

                                    // Initialize the sharedPreferences editor
                                    Editor editor = pref.edit();

                                    // get value in field
                                    String value = field.getText().toString();

                                    // pair the value in text field with the key
                                    editor.putString(key, value);

                                    editor.commit();
                                }
                            }
                        })

                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create an alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertD = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertD.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you add the exception, please?

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

`final EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(id)`

by :

`final EditText field = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(id)`

since the editText is contained in the promptView and not in the Activity Layout.

Comment: That can't work because the variable id contains the id of the clicked button (as example the positive button)

Answer (score 0):

You get an exception because your id of the EditText is not the parameter in the method of onClick.
The variable id is the id of the button that was clicked. You have to use:

```
 final EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html#onClick(android.content.DialogInterface,%20int)) there it is explained what the variable id is.

Answer (score 0):

in `onclick()` use this:

```
final EditText field = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(id)
```